# How can I compile against iOS SDK 3.1.2 on Yosemite (Xcode 6)?

Tags: ios, sdk, compilation

I need to compile an Xcode (iOS) project that targets iOS SDK 3.1.2, but I'm currently running Yosemite and Xcode 6.

What do I need to do or download to compile/target this much older iOS version?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with Xcode 6. It's just not possible!

You may want to set the deployment target to iOS 5.1.1 though. You cannot go below that without losing the ability to submit the app to the app store.

With an older version of Xcode, it should be possible to compile for iOS 3.1.2, but you'll lose the ability to submit the binary to the app store. In any case, you should always use the latest SDK. E.g. you may use the iOS 7 SDK and set the iOS deployment target to iOS 5.1.1